# Contract law: implicit payment?

Tags: contract-law

If I enter an establishment that offers drinks/coffee/food and say "I'd like a coffee/beer/whatever" and the waiter gives it to me, shouldn't they explicitly mention that it's not for free?

If some person is handling pens with ads on a corner, and I say "I'd like a pen" could the person just reply that it's $1?

Would the scenarios above be any different if a mentally challenged person went through them?

Answer (score 2):

> If I enter an establishment that offers drinks/coffee/food and say "I'd like a coffee/beer/whatever" and the waiter gives it to me, shouldn't they explicitly mention that it's not for free?

No. Contracts don't happen in a vacuum - the circumstances described make it abundantly clear to a reasonable person that the drinks are not gifts.

> If some person is handling pens with ads on a corner, and I say "I'd like a pen" could the person just reply that it's $1?

Yes. Just because they give something to someone else doesn't mean they have to give one to you.

> Would the scenarios above be any different if a mentally challenged person went through them?

Maybe. However, the mental impairment would need to be [extreme and obvious](https://www.alrc.gov.au/publication/equality-capacity-and-disability-in-commonwealth-laws-dp-81/11-other-issues/incapacity-and-contract-law/):

> In order to avoid the contract on the ground of incapacity, the onus is on the party seeking to have the contract avoided to first establish that: (a) the contracting party was unable, due to mental impairment, to understand the contract at the time of formation; and (b) that the other party either knew or ought to have known of the impairment.

Answer (score 2):

> If I enter an establishment that offers drinks/coffee/food and say "I'd like a coffee/beer/whatever" and the waiter gives it to me, shouldn't they explicitly mention that it's not for free?

No. Visitors/customers know very well it is common practice for those establishments to charge an amount in exchange for drinks/coffee/food. That common knowledge satisfies the contract law premise that the "clause" of payment is "entered" *knowingly* (and willfully) by the establishment and the customer.

In fact, that practice is so common that the establishment makes it very explicit --usually with publicity and notorious signs-- when it intends to provide goods for free. Thus, there are no grounds for you to reasonably expect that the good(s) at issue will be free in an ordinary situation.

> If some person is handling pens with ads on a corner, and I say "I'd like a pen" could the person just reply that it's $1?

Yes (perhaps putting aside any particular scenarios of discrimination on the basis of protected categories).

For instance, the person's intent for the ads on the pens might be to reach a market sector to which you don't belong. Thus, in your case, the person might want an alternative benefit (namely, the amount of $1) to spend his pen/ad on you, since he knows that his advertising/marketing purpose is preempted here.

> Would the scenarios above be any different if a mentally challenged person went through them?

They could be different, as mentioned in the other answer.